# Can't get Eclipse to recognize my Ideatab

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

I had been using my PlayBook for Android dev but recently got a Lenovo Idea tab but I can't deploy to it from Eclipse. I enabled dev mode in the settings and tried installing the Android usb drivers from the sdk but it says the best driver is already installed. What else should I try?

Comment: Is debugging enabled? Also, check the way the phone connects, you want it to be something along the lines of PC only. You can also try `adb devices` from your terminal, to see if the adb bridge recognizes the device, if it doesn't then it's an issue with the device settings. If it does, then it's not the device.

Comment: Yes debugging is enabled. adb devies says "list of devices attached" but doesn't show any.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the phone drivers onto your computer. Visit the device manufacturers web site and you should be able to get the drivers you need to install on your PC, then, once you install those, you should be able to connect to you comp. It should be noted these drivers are different than the ones you already installed.

Good luck!

Comment: I downloaded that, deleted the device from device manager and installed the downloaded drivers, rebooted and still no luck. It's showing Driver Date: 21/06/2006 in device manager so I'm thinking it's not really getting updated.

Comment: You'll want to google your idea tab model number and drivers; so, `ideatab a-2354 drivers`

Comment: Hm it appears there is no driver for this model a2109a-f. I see where someone posted in the lenovo forum that the other driver I tried should work but windows won't let me install it, possibly because I'm running Win 7 x64

Comment: You can install a 32 bit program on a 64 bit system. You just have to put it in the x86 directory